# Cannot call value of non-function type 'CGFloat'

Tags: swift, swift4

I am new to sprite kit 2d game development. it's existing swift2 project working well but unfortunately after update swift4 flowing code getting error. How can i resolve this

```
class SGScene : SKScene {
      override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            //let location = touch.locationInNode(self) //swift2
            let location = touch.location(self) //getting error update Xcode suggestion
            screenInteractionStarted(location)
        }
    }

       func screenInteractionStarted(_ location : CGPoint) {
            /*Overridden by Subclass*/
        }
}
```

currently I try to update this project swift4

Comment: Just `for touch in touches { ... }`.

Comment: @Rob thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´re missing the parameter name: `in`. Repalce this line:

```
let location = touch.location(self)
```

With:

```
let location = touch.location(in: self)
```

And it will work.

The entire class:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class SGScene : SKScene {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            screenInteractionStarted(location)
        }
    }

    func screenInteractionStarted(_ location : CGPoint) {
        /*Overridden by Subclass*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you have something else that´s not working, just tried this and it´s compiling fine.

Comment: oh! it is working but can you share with how you get this fix or update method calling syntax

Comment: please help me to fix error   this line please `myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))`

Comment: Something like this `myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY, width: myLabel.frame.size.width, height: myLabel.frame.size.height)`

Comment: Cannot assign to property: 'frame' is a get-only property

Answer (score 0):

Replace your method with this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touches.forEach { touch in
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        screenInteractionStarted(location)
    }
}
```